# Is there a common meaning for vector $x_{ij}$ if only $x_i$ and $x_j$ are defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I have a [physics simulation paper](http://blog.mmacklin.com/flex/), where $x_i$ and $x_j$ are three dimensional coordinates. Suddenly they use $x_{ij}$ without defining it. I have no experience with scientific literature. Is there a common meaning for that?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you mention the equations in the paper, please? :)

Comment: Of course, it occurs e.g. in eq. 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the position vector of the $i_{th}$ and $j_{th}$ particles are denoted by $x_i$ and $x_j$. According to the context of your paper which is dealing with particles, it simply means

$$x_i-x_j = x_{ij}$$

which means the vector from the $i_{th}$ particle to $j_{th}$ particle.

[image]

Comment: Is it mentioned somewhere?

Comment: After staring at the paper for $5$ minutes, I see no justification for this claim...

Comment: @5xum: It is a usual convention in physics and they don't mention it every time. :)

Comment: @mak: No, it is just a usual convention.

Comment: Ah, OK. Now your answer makes sense.

Comment: @mak: I added a picture for better comprehension. :) Good Luck. :)